# How to get customer default tax code ref

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Our customers have already setup all of their customer information, including default tax codes in QBO. Our web app is pushing invoices to QBO, but when you create an invoice via the API and do not specify the taxcoderef, the QBO import does NOT pickup the customer's default tax code that is setup in their profile.

And to take it further, if we wanted to replicate that info in our web app, there is no way to pull the customer's default tax code via the api either:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Customer

So they have to replicate their efforts and we'll have to give them the ability to setup each customer's default tax code within our web app and then we can send it along with the invoice.

Am I missing some way to pull the customer's default tax code?